# Javascript library dependencies check

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies

Is there any tools that can help list the dependencies of a given javascript library?

say:

depcheck jqgrid@5.1.1

I am aware that a similar feature is provided by npm but that requires a dedicated structure. I am working on a legacy code base without such structure (no package.json file).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/package.json

If it is published as an npm module, and on github, you can check out the package.json file in the github repo.

Comment: hmm, that wasn't bad, but does require manual check of each individual javascript then (rather than using a CLI command)?

at worst case, I can get that info. :)

Comment: Within the requirements of your project, can you reinstall all the modules with npm? If you could, you could use this inside the project folder `"npm list --depth=0 2>/dev/null"`

Comment: you can also use a similar command to get a list of all globally installed modules if you have npm on your system: `npm list -g --depth=0 2>/dev/null`